# DocumentDb - get Json representation of Document

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

Is there a simple/any solution for putting JSON representation of Document data (without DocDb native properties like _rid etc.) into response (in stored procedures) or is there a solution somewhere in Microsoft.Azure.Documents namespace?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's delete operator to strip out DocumentDB's native properties. Take a look at this thread: [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Something like this should work:

```
delete doc._rid;
delete doc._ts;
delete doc._etag;
getContext().getResponse().setBody(doc);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. There's quite a few solutions when it comes to removing properties from an object (sproc, inside the controller(MVC wise) etc.) I was just hoping for a "native" solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same question. I found this way (in C#):

```
dynamic d = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(doc.ToString());
string versionData = d["Employees"]["@version"];
string employeeNameData = d["Employees"]["@name"];
```

Where "Employees" is the Document name (i.e., table name in Sql terms), and version is a attribute of that document.

This way you can make a generic query over any data stored internally in the document. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Of course you can also do the following directly: 

dynamic jsonObj = doc; (where doc is the Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document)

but, then you can't do the following:
    string versionData = d["Employees"]["@version"];
and you have to do:
    string versionData = d.Employees.["@version"];
which makes it a bit un-generic